# Upload file translate text in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I cannot find the strings "Choose file" and "No file selected" in an upload input form widget, so I can translate them. Where are they located? Or are they embedded into php and not in symfony2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These text is defined by the browser and not by PHP or Symfony. You will also notice that this widget will be displayed differently in different browsers and on different operating systems. There is no possibility to change the text displayed in this widget. There is also no possibility to change the design of the widget. Most CSS properties won't have an effect on `<input type="file">`.

The only thing that you could do is to implement a custom JavaScript uploader, but that will probably only work in modern browsers. I personally have never done this, but a quick Google search brought up [this page](http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins) that features 7 different JavaScript plugins to do this.

Comment: Absolutely straightforward. This is what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Florian says, these texts are output by the browser and you cannot change or style them. You may use a javascript uploader, but this may be overkill for most cases. But there is a "hack" that you can use to overlay your own styled file upload input on top of the standard file upload, it is explained [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html). It needs javascript to run but the good thing is that if javascript is not available it just defaults to your standard file input.